# Android studio Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am very new to android programming and this application I'm working on always throws a null object reference. I want to change the color of the circle if I press a colored button. My reset button also throws the same error and I don't know how to fix it. I tried everything I know and can't find any answer. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myname.fingerpaintapplication;


import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.draw_view);

        Button myRedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
        myRedButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button myBlueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue);
        myBlueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button myGreenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGreen);
        myGreenButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button myBrownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBrown);
        myBrownButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button myVioletButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViolet);
        myVioletButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button myYellowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYellow);
        myYellowButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button myExitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
        myExitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button myResetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReset);
        myResetButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button mySaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        mySaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button btnPressed = (Button)view;


            if(btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonRed)
            {
                drawView.setColors(0xffff0000);
                // use system log to indicate button1 pressed
                Log.e("buttonRed","clicked");

                // drawView.setColors(#ffff0000);

                CharSequence text = "Red color selected";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

            else if(btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonBlue)
            {
                // use system log to indicate button1 pressed
                Log.e("buttonBlue","clicked");
                drawView.setColors(Color.BLUE);
                //  pressedColor = Color.parseColor();
                // create a Toast message
                CharSequence text = "Blue color selected";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
            else if(btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonGreen)
            {
                // use system log to indicate button1 pressed
                Log.e("buttonGreen","clicked");
                drawView.setColors(0x008000);
                //  pressedColor = Color.parseColor();
                // create a Toast message
                CharSequence text = "Green color selected";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
            else if(btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonBrown)
            {
                // use system log to indicate button1 pressed
                Log.e("buttonBrown","clicked");
                drawView.setColors(0xa5682a);
                //  pressedColor = Color.parseColor();
                // create a Toast message
                CharSequence text = "Brown color selected";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
            else if(btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonViolet)
            {
                // use system log to indicate button1 pressed
                Log.e("buttonViolet","clicked");
                drawView.setColors(0xFFC0CB);
                //  pressedColor = Color.parseColor();
                // create a Toast message
                CharSequence text = "Violet color selected";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
            else if(btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonYellow)
            {
                // use system log to indicate button1 pressed
                Log.e("buttonYellow","clicked");
                drawView.setColors(0xffff00);
                //  pressedColor = Color.parseColor();
                // create a Toast message
                CharSequence text = "Yellow color selected";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }

            else if(btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonReset)
            {

                AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                newDialog.setTitle("Reset painting");
                newDialog.setMessage("Start new painting? You will lose the current painting if you proceed");
                newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        drawView.reset();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                newDialog.show();
            }

            else if (btnPressed.getId() == R.id.buttonExit)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                newDialog.setTitle("Exit application");
                newDialog.setMessage("Exit the application?");
                newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        finish();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                newDialog.show();
            }


    }

}
```

And this is my custom View:

```
package com.example.myname.fingerpaintapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


public class DrawView extends View{

    public final static int CircleRadius = 50;
    public final static int START_X = 0;
    public final static int START_Y = 0;
    private Paint paint, paintCanvas = new Paint();
    private int paintCode = 0xffff0000;
    private Bitmap customBitmap;
    private Canvas customCanvas;


    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }


    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this (context);
        drawSomething();
        //super(context, attrs);

    }

    private void drawSomething(){
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap( customBitmap, START_X, START_Y, paintCanvas);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        customBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        customCanvas = new Canvas(customBitmap);
        customCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }



    public void reset(){
        invalidate();
        customCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    }

    public void setColors(int newColor){
        //paintCode = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        //paint = new Paint();
        paintCode = newColor;
        paint.setColor(paintCode);
        invalidate();

//        paintCode = Color.parseColor(newColor);
//        paint.setColor(Integer.parseInt(newColor));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        customCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, CircleRadius, paint);

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


}
```

and my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.myname.fingerpaintapplication.MainActivity"
    android:background="#11b8dd">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonYellow"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonViolet"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonViolet" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonGreen"
        android:background="#008000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonRed"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonYellow"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonBlue"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonGreen"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonYellow" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonViolet"
        android:background="#FFC0CB"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGreen"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrown"
        android:background="#a5682a"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonGreen"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonBlue" />

    <com.example.myname.fingerpaintapplication.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/draw_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonYellow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:id="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonSave" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonReset"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonTriangle"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:background="#11b8dd"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonYellow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonTriangle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButtonTriangle"
        android:paddingTop="7dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_switch_thumb_material"
        android:background="#11b8dd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I press the red button, it should change the color of the ball but instead it throws a null object reference. How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Here is the error:

```
09-01 13:49:28.240 19321-19321/com.example.francisjan.fingerpaintapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                               Process: com.example.francisjan.fingerpaintapplication, PID: 19321
                                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.francisjan.fingerpaintapplication.DrawView.setColors(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                   at com.example.myname.fingerpaintapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please, as a minimum, post your LogCat, and also try to make a [mcve].

Comment: I used the try and catch to see what's wrong and it really is the null object reference.

Comment: The problem must be in my setColors() and reset() method but I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your `DrawView.java`

about line 29,it should be

```
 public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    drawSomething();
}
```

You forget to invole the super method!!

Comment: thanks for that. my reset button works now.
the reason i changed that to: 
    this(context);
is because last time, every time I press on the screen it errors, but it works now. thanks again :)

Comment: No worries. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it's useful for you .

Comment: I still have the buttons for changing the colors. It doesn't throw an error now but it still does not change the color when i press it.

Comment: In the `setColors` method, before `invalidate();` , add `customCanvas.drawColor(newColor);`;             Don't konw wether this is what you want.

Comment: That changes the color of my view (the canvas). When i press the screen it draws a black circle and when I press the button i want the next circle to be that color i chose

Comment: I see. If you find only bule and green work,you should change your code. use `drawView.setColors(Color.YELLOW);`  instead of `drawView.setColors(0xffff00);`

Comment: Oh yeah, I wonder why. It doesn't work on violet and brown.
I still can't figure out why it does not change the color of the circle(paint of the circle)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I just messed up with the use of the paint variable inside the OnTouchEvent method. Here is the fixed custom View:

```
package com.example.myname.fingerpaintapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


public class DrawView extends View{

    public final static int CircleRadius = 50;
    public final static int START_X = 0;
    public final static int START_Y = 0;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    private Bitmap customBitmap;
    private Canvas customCanvas = new Canvas();


    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        drawSomething();
    }

    /*Creates a new paint*/
    private void drawSomething(){

        paint = new Paint();
    }

    /**/
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap( customBitmap, START_X, START_Y, paint);
        rect.set(START_X, START_Y, 150, 150);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        customBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        customCanvas = new Canvas(customBitmap);
        customCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    /*method that resets the view*/
    public void reset(){
        customCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        invalidate();
    }

    /*method that changes the color of the paint*/
    public void setColors(int newColor){
        paint.setColor(newColor);
        invalidate();
    }


    /*method that gets where the user touches on the screen*/
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        customCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, CircleRadius, paint);


        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And for the changing of colors when you press the button in the main Activity, I used this code:

```
drawView.setColors(Color.rgb(139,69,19));
```

this color is for brown, and the other colors, i just search their corresponding RGB color codes.